# How to evaluate the following items in mathematical methods in physics?

Tags: sequences-and-series, indefinite-integrals, generating-functions, mathematical-physics, frobenius-method

I had taken a long break from math and physics for months due to stress and an illness so when I returned to it and tried answering problems given, I had difficulty figuring out how to do some of them all over again. Here were the items I had encountered:

1) Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {p^n}{sin(2nx)}$

2) Solve for x(t):
$\frac{dx}{dt} = x_o =-cos(t)x + t^3, x(t=0)$

3) Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{(a+cos\theta)^2}, a>1$

4) Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {x^6 e^{-x^2}} dx$

5) Evaluate $L_n(0)$ given the generating function for Laguerre polynomials is $g(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} L_n(x) t^n = \frac {e^{xt/(1-t)}}{1-t}$

6) Solve: $y'' + x^2 y'+(x-1)y = 0$ 
-> For this, I tried the Frobenius method but didn't get far.

Some weren't taught in my previous class but I was expected to already know it for my course this coming semester. I have tried searching already but I have not gotten far for these. I am not expecting all of these to be answered. I just really need help getting started again so any help for any of these would be really appreciated. You can just choose one among them. If you could perhaps give me a way I can try, step-by-step, or a really good reference for me to look at so I can self-study.

Comment: Please, only one question per post.

Comment: Sorry, will do!

Comment: It looks like you are not ready for that course.

Comment: I had a pretty bad professor previously and so I have to self-study everything before I can take the next course. I know I'm not ready that's why I'm doing something about it now :)

Comment: Terrible question. Should never have been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINTS:**

For $1)$, write

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n\sin(2nx)=\text{Im}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (p\,e^{i2x})^n\right)\tag1$$

Then sum the geometric series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ and take the imaginary part of that result.

---

For $3)$, note that

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{(a+\cos(\theta))^2}\,d\theta=-\frac{d}{da}\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{a+\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\tag 2$$

The integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ can be evaluated using the classical [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) or contour integration.  Finish by taking the derivative with respect to $a$ and multiplying by $-1$.

---

For $4)$ note that

$$\int_0^\infty x^6e^{-x^2}\,dx=-\left.\left(\frac{d^3}{da^3}\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,dx\right)\right|_{a=1} \tag 3$$

The integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ is the form of the classical [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#The_integral_of_a_Gaussian_function).  Take its third derivative, evaluate at $a=1$, and multiply by $-1$.

Comment: For 1, how was the summation equal to that (the imaginary part)? Do we only get the imaginary part because it's sin(2nx)?

For 3 and 4, how did the 2 side of the equation become equal? 

Also, thank you for your hints! :)

Comment: For $1)$, note that $\sin(2nx)=\text{Im}(e^{i2nx})$.  For $3)$ and $4)$, differentiate under the integral.  And, you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Also, I just responded to the comment of making one post per question and I posted it before you replied to my query and maybe it would be further explained if I did it one per post. Anyway, I really appreciate the hints for some of the items! I don't use this often so I'm not sure how to up vote but I will!